# ¿Cómo obtener timestamp desde una fecha para una dataframe con SQL?

Tags: sql, python

Quiero recuperar con una consulta sql dates con el formato `timestamp` en `dataframes` python modificar esta última para obtener los resultados esperados.

Utilizo PostgreSQL sobre DataGrip pero no sé cual esta la versión.

Hizo :

```
SELECT CAST(swipe.date AS TIMESTAMP) FROM swipe
GROUP BY swipe.date
```

Pero no funciona, consigo una fecha normal.

Con python, traigo :

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""
    SELECT  swipe.eclipse_id, swipe.subscriber_id, COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.date FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id,swipe.date
      ORDER BY (swipe.subscriber_id) ASC;
    """)
    n = cur.fetchall()
        listado_n = [{"eclipse_id": elem[0], "subscriber_id": elem[1], "count": elem[2],"date":elem[3]} for elem in n]

df = pd.DataFrame(listado_n)

import time
timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(df['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Y no funciona tampoco.

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda saber como te retornan los datos de la columna fecha. ¿Qué te retorna la consulta `cur.execute("SELECT swipe.date FROM swipe")` exactamente? ¿Podrías aportar un ejemplo real de lo que te retorna esta consulta?

Comment: Podrías probar convirtiendo la fecha a texto desde la consulta, ejemplo 
    SELECT to_char(swipe.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') FROM swipe